# Want to Set controls width with respect to Div in CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a scenario in which i need to show a input button alignment based on div control.The width of div will vary so i want that with respect to div width my input button will set it's width.Here i m goin to paste two images

***Image 1 :-***

[image]

In first image the width of `div` is `100px` so the *save* and *close* button must be placed above grid like it show here.If the width of div increased then Input button must move with it.

***Image 2:-***

[image]

In second case if div width increased then Buttons position moves with div width.

Edit:-

```
<div class="outer">
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Save" />
        <input id="Submit2" type="submit" value="Close" />
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
</div>
```

This is my scenarion,here position of button will depend on the position of `inner` div not the `outer` one.

Hope you understand.

*Note :- Buttons alignment or position totally depend upon `div` `width` or `alignment`.*

Comment: The "alignment" part confuses me a lot. I would agree with @Mr.Alien – we need some code

Comment: @Mr.Alien just check my updated question.

Comment: @Rahul I already answered

Comment: @Rahul, aren't the provided answers solve your issue of both alignment and width? If not, I think you should provide us with more information.

Answer (score 1):

Hello mate i did a try:

CSS:

```
.container {
height:200px;
width:400px;
border:solid;}

.close {
width:33%;
float:right;
border:solid;
height:100px;}

.save{
width:33%;
float:right;
border:solid;
height:100px;
margin-right:10px;}

.content {
position:relative;
   width:100%;
height:90px;
border:solid;
bottom:2px;
float:right;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="close"></div>
<div class="save"></div>
<div class="content"></div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pNZ62/2/

Of course you can style it better! :P
Btw increase or decrease the width of the container to see that it works!
Hope I helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all the three blocks in a div and give widths of each block in percentages.

```
.save{width:20%;}
.close{width:20%;}
div{width:90%;}
```

Comment: How would this produce the result in the question? could you provide a fiddle please?

Comment: You are making too many assumptions. Do you know what is the container element? Do you know how many divs are in the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a container element that wraps both the div and the inputs, then set the inputs width to a percentage that suits your needs, for example 25% for each input and 100% for the div

Comment: This technically repeats the answer from @Wisam I guess.

Comment: Does it? How exactly does it repeat it?

Comment: I would say "textually", @Leo ;) You are describing the same solution as it is in the answer by Wisam, aren't you? But maybe I confuse something.

Comment: Perhaps since it looks like a straight-forward solution. Yet, i left the answer a bit abstract since the question is too abstract as well

Answer (score 0):

**[Here is the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/h7LH9/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Save" />
    <input id="Submit2" type="submit" value="Close" />
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Submit1, #Submit2 {
    width: 22%;
    float: right;    
}
.inner {
    width: 100%;
    clear: right;
}
```